# include extra argument to callback in google analytics data api

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, google-analytics-api

Consider example code from [google analytics api docs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/2.0/gdataJavascript.html#handleDataFeed):

```
function getDataFeed() {
var myFeedUri = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data' +
    '?start-date=2009-04-01' +
    '&end-date=2009-04-30' +
    '&dimensions=ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath' +
    '&metrics=ga:pageviews' +
    '&sort=-ga:pageviews' +
    '&max-results=10' +
    '&ids=' + document.getElementById('tableId').value;

  myService.getDataFeed(myFeedUri, handleDataFeed, handleError);
}

function handleDataFeed(result) {
 // An array of Analytics feed entries.
 var entries = result.feed.getEntries();
 ....
}
```

My javascript app is sending GA api requests with different feed arguments, and different states of variables in my app. Because of async responses, when sending multiple requests simultaneously things get mixed up in handling the results.

Is there a way to include an extra argument to the callback function (handleDataFeed) in the request which can be picked up when handling the results?
Or are there other ways I can solve this, preferably without having to create a queue of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a closure for the callback function so the extra data is available via lexical scoping:

```
function getDataFeed() {
    var myFeedUri = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data' +
        '?start-date=2009-04-01' +
        '&end-date=2009-04-30' +
        '&dimensions=ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath' +
        '&metrics=ga:pageviews' +
        '&sort=-ga:pageviews' +
        '&max-results=10' +
        '&ids=' + document.getElementById('tableId').value;

      var extraData = "extra data here";

      myService.getDataFeed(myFeedUri, function(result) {
         // An array of Analytics feed entries.
         var entries = result.feed.getEntries();

         // Extra data still in scope here
         alert(extraData);

         ....
      }, handleError);
    }
```